# The mArrow3 function in Matlab behaves weird

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I'm using the mArrow3 function to show plane's orientation.
But, sometimes any dart behaves weird.

The code I'm using:

```
drawnow;
xExt = abs(diff(get(gca, 'XLim')));
yExt = abs(diff(get(gca, 'YLim')));
zExt = abs(diff(get(gca, 'ZLim')));
mArrow3([0 0 0],[xExt / 1, 0, 0], 'lineWidth', 2,'color','red','facealpha',  0.1);
mArrow3([0 0 0],[0, yExt / 1, 0], 'lineWidth',  2,'color','red','facealpha',0.1);
mArrow3([0 0 0],[0, 0, zExt / 1], 'lineWidth',  2,'color','red','facealpha',0.1);


text(xExt, 0, 0, 'Vx','FontSize',12);  
text(0, yExt, 0, 'Vy','FontSize',12); 
text(0, 0, zExt, 'Vz','FontSize',12);
```

Could you please give me any hint on this issue?

Comment: "Behaves weird"... we're going to need more to go on than that.

Comment: What is `mArrow3`?

Comment: It is a function, that enables showing plane's orientation. In this case red arrows.

Comment: By weird I mean as you can see in the picture, the width of Vx differs from Vy and Vz. I don't know why, because the settings are the same.

Comment: It is not a built-in function. Where is it? See: [mcve]

Comment: Try `axes equal`

Comment: It's a function downloaded from https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25372-marrow3-m-easy-to-use-3d-arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the inline documentation of `mArrow3` ([MATLAB FEX](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25372-marrow3-m-easy-to-use-3d-arrow/)) the three properties that control the line appearance are:

```
% properties: 'color':      color according to MATLAB specification
%                           (see MATLAB help item 'ColorSpec')
%             'stemWidth':  width of the line
%             'tipWidth':   width of the cone
```

As you can see, `'lineWidth'` is not one of those options. To understand why you're seeing the above behavior, you can look at the function definition to see what happens if these values are not passed in the function call:

```
%% default parameters
if ~exist('stemWidth','var')
    ax = axis;
    if numel(ax)==4
        stemWidth = norm(ax([2 4])-ax([1 3]))/300;
    elseif numel(ax)==6
        stemWidth = norm(ax([2 4 6])-ax([1 3 5]))/300;
    end
end
if ~exist('tipWidth','var')
    tipWidth = 3*stemWidth;
end
```

As you can see, if `stemWidth` and `tipWidth` are not provided, `mArrow3` normalizes their values based on the axis limits and `stemWidth`, respectively.

So why does it not throw an error? If you look further into the function definition you can look at the error checking:

```
%% draw
fv.faces = f;
fv.vertices = v;
h = patch(fv);
for propno = 1:numel(propertyNames)
    try
        set(h,propertyNames{propno},propertyValues{propno});
    catch
        disp(lasterr)
    end
end
```

What this does is use a [try/catch block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) to [set](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) the properties you've passed that aren't `'color'`, `'stemWidth'`, or `'tipWidth'`. If they're not valid properties for the [`patch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) object, `set` will throw an error, which is caught and displayed to keep the function from erroring out completely. If you check out the [`Patch` properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html), you'll see that [`'lineWidth'` is a valid property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html#property_d0e725116), so `set` will not error. However, it controls the width of the patch edges, which I'm guessing is not the property you actually want to adjust.

Comment: Using stemWidth instead of lineWidth made the arrows disappear and only the text is appearing.

Comment: Probably because `2` is about `0.08%` the size of your smallest axes extent. You'll need to normalize them to your axes.

Comment: Works better, I used number 10 instead of 2, but it appears flat, not 3D, and the length is not the same in all cases. And sometimes the cones appear only merge and the lines don't appear.

Comment: In conclusion, it does not behave the same all the times.

Comment: Given that your axes are not uniform, you're going to need to manipulate the parameters individually or come up with a normalization that provides the desired visual.